# C++ error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and have a simple Date class where I am trying to set a value for the Date.

Here are the source code files -

Date.h

```
class Date{ 
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

public:
    Date();
    void setDate(int m, int d, int y);

};
```

and Date.cpp

```
#include "Date.h"

Date::Date()
{
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
    year = 80;

};

void Date :: setDate(int m1, int d1, int y1){
    month = m1;
    day = d1;
    year = y1;
};
```

However, when I compile the code, I get the error message -

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a main function.  Add this to either a new file (like main.cpp, and include it when compiling and linking) or to your other .cpp file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  }
```

And put your code to run the program in the braces.

Answer (score 1):

Every C/C++ program must have a `main` function which unconditionally serves as the entry point of your program's execution.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Date d;
  d.setDate(11, 19, 1984);

  /* do something with this date... */

  return 0;
}
```

A common convention is to place this in `main.cc` / `main.cpp` and ensure, in this case, that both `main.cpp` and `Date.cpp` are compiled *and linked* into the same target binary.  A linker will not proceed without being able to resolve `main(int, char**)`.  If this is obvious to you, then I'd simply ask you to check your linker command line to ensure that the source/object file containing `main` is included.

Also, random C++ best practices guideline: you should have a non-default constructor that takes the arguments that `setDate` does and assigns them to your member variables via an initializer list. In this case, a default constructor (no arguments) makes little sense for your concrete date class.